# Variation on the Coupon Problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Suppose you are collecting coupons where each of the n types of coupons have a uniform probability of occurring when a purchase is made. To win one requires k coupons of the same type (can be any type). I'm trying to find a reoccurrence relation that will give the expected number of purchases that need to be made before one gets their kth coupon of any type.

I've been stuck on this problem for awhile and am looking for any hints on how to proceed. I know that this is a variation of the standard coupon problem, but I haven't been able to figure out a means of finding the expected number of purchases based on k and n, or any examples of this kind of coupon problem.

Answer (score 1):

Of the general class of occupancy or collision problems, I think this is more like the birthday problem than the coupon-collector's problem, particularly if $k=2$

Let $q(m,n,k)$ be the probability that you have *not* won after $m$ attempts, i.e. the probability that the distribution of $m$ coupons among $n$ types does *not* have $k$ or more of any particular type

Then I think that for $k \le m, n \gt 0$ you have $$q(m,n,k)= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} {m \choose j}\frac{(n-1)^{m-j}}{n^m}q(m-j,n-1,k)$$

as well as the obvious

- $q(0,0,k)=1$
- $q(m,0,k)=0 \text{ for } n \gt 0$
- $q(m,n,k)=1 \text{ for } 0 \le m \lt k, n \gt 0$

You will find that $q(k,n,k)= 1-\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}$ while $q(nk-n,n,k)= \frac{(nk-n)!}{((k-1)!)^n\, n^{nk-n}}$ and, as you would hope from the pigeon-hole principle, $q(nk-n+1,n,k)=0$

The expected number of attempts until you win (including the winning attempt) is then $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{nk-k} q(m,n,k)$$

So for example if $k=3$, you get the following (rounded) values for $q$:

```
    n 1   2        3         4          5          6
 m    - ----- --------- ---------- ---------- -----------
 0    1 1.000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.000000000
 1    1 1.000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.000000000
 2    1 1.000 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.000000000
 3    0 0.750 0.8888889 0.93750000 0.96000000 0.972222222
 4    0 0.375 0.6666667 0.79687500 0.86400000 0.902777778
 5    0 0.000 0.3703704 0.58593750 0.71040000 0.787037037
 6    0 0.000 0.1234568 0.35156250 0.51840000 0.632716049
 7    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.15380859 0.32256000 0.459104938
 8    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.03845215 0.16128000 0.292566872
 9    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.05806080 0.157536008
10    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.01161216 0.067515432
11    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.020629715
12    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.003438286
13    0 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
```

Adding up the columns gives `3 4.125 5.0493827 5.86413628 6.60631330 7.295544434` representing the expected values when $k=3$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$.  Looking at different values of $k$, and at $n=365$ to match the birthday problem, you get this table of expected values

```
    n 1   2         3         4         5         6          365 
 k   --  --------  -------- --------- --------- --------- ----------  
 1    1  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    1.00000
 2    2  2.500000  2.888889  3.218750  3.510400  3.774691   24.61659
 3    3  4.125000  5.049383  5.864136  6.606313  7.295544   88.73892
 4    4  5.812500  7.348270  8.730541 10.010009 11.213757  187.05178
 5    5  7.539062  9.734204 11.736762 13.609403 15.385788  311.44938
 6    6  9.292969 12.181254 14.841424 17.346933 19.737384  456.01628
 7    7 11.067383 14.674221 18.020165 21.188563 24.224483  616.61692
 8    8 12.857910 17.203304 21.257233 25.112238 28.818468  790.29969
 9    9 14.661530 19.761754 24.541762 29.102717 33.499535  974.89387
10   10 16.476059 22.344688 27.865883 33.148950 38.253314 1168.75672
```

The $24.61659$ for $n=365$ and $k=2$ is a [known value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people)